# Rust Diesel failing to compile with linker error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I was using Diesel and it was working with the following `Cargo.toml` config:

```toml
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres"] }
```

Running without Diesel and everything is fine. When I introduce the above dependency it fails to compile with the following error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

OS: MacOS Big Sur

**Update**
I've installed libpq with the following command:

```
brew install libpq
```

I then tried to link it with the following command:

```
brew link --force libpq
```

This worked. Thanks for the comments that pointed me into this direction.

Comment: Is this the full error message?

Comment: Do you have postgres installed?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed thanks for some reason my installation was unlinked and this solved the problem. I've updated the question. Put your comment as an answer and I can select it as a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have postgres installed correctly on your system:

```rust
// ubuntu
$ sudo apt install libpq-dev

// osx
$ brew install libpq
```